# Any ideas for how to let an Agent create new actions?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

If we break 'make coffee' down into discrete actions there is practically no end to how minute actions can become.

> To Make Coffee do:
>   To Open Drawer do:
>   To Move Hand to Drawer do:
>   To Raise Hand 30 inches do:
>   To Engage Arm, Shoulder, and Back muscles do:

And so on.  When our high level functioning brains want to make coffee we don't consider all our choices of how to wrap our fingers around the drawer handle, as it has been practiced many times.  Has anyone thought about how to let Agents create their own actions as strings of previous actions?

I guess some obstacles would be: Ways to let the Agent interrupt a drawn out action based on state change.  Ways to transfer value to another action while using a neural net.  Ways to increase/cull action spaces.

Comment: In Sutton & Barto, they briefly suggest a fixed hierarchy of controllers to address this problem. In human learning it would appear to be more fluid (e.g. often learning a skill such as playing an instrument involves directed conscious effort to learn low level skills which are later strung together semi-consciously or unconsciously). I expect there is some research into this (I don't know even what to search for), although we are still at early days in terms of transfer learning/learning by analogy etc, so I don't think you will find any ready algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there has been some research on this topic, to compose primitive actions to macro actions.

As a starting point, you can use this reference:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3325518/